# R - expand.grid with dataset having columns of different sizes

Tags: r

I want to produce a matrix which holds all possible combinations of a vector x of integers from 1 to the respective number. 
The length of the vector x may change.

For this sample vector:

```
x = c(3,8,2)
```

I want the result to look something like this:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
   [1,]   1    1    1  
   [2,]   1    1    2 
   [3,]   1    2    1 
...
   [48,]  3    8    2
```

I understand expand.grid does the job, however, I can't seem to find the parameters which allow for different sets in each column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We get the sequence of each element (`seq`) and do `expand.grid`

```
out <- expand.grid(lapply(x, seq))
dim(out)
#[1] 48  3
```